# Print- grep the text's path from sub directories -Unix

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Suppose I have this line of text:

*How are you?*

Now I want to print the path of the file that has the text as 'How are you'.

I would really appreciate the help on this.

Comment: `grep -l` prints the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU grep you could use the `-R` flag to have `grep` search recursively for matches.  If your `grep` doesn't support that flag you could use `find` together with it like

```
find "path_to_start" -type f -exec grep -l "How are you?" {} +
```

which will exec `grep -l "How are you?" for each file found anywhere under`path_to_start`(well, with`{} +`it might invoke`grep` with many files at once, but the output is the same).

Though with GNU `grep` it can be

```
grep -Rl "How are you?" "path_to_start"
```

where in both commands you replace `"path_to_start"` with the root in which you want to begin your search